# Why gdb can't find my shared object library?

Tags: gdb, ld

Please IGNORE my post. 
I must have been the 1000000th person to discover that gdb resets LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Sorry if you have wasted some of your time!

For the record, the solution is *not* to say inside gdb

`set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc.etc`

because that will be ignored too.
Instead, since gdb starts a new shell in which your code will be executed, put that into your .profile or .tcshrc or .bashrc or whatnot. gdb will then obey.
Cheers!
-------------------------------- snip snip snip ------------------------------------

This has stumped me for a long time.

I am trying to work with a graphical package called ImageMagick, and I have the simplest program :

`#include <iostream>`

`#include <Magick++.h>`

`using namespace Magick;`

`int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {`

`Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);`

`std::cout << "Here I didit!" << std::endl;`

`}`

I create the executable easy enough, like this:

`g++ -g -o testIM testIM.cc "Magick++-config --cxxflags --libs"`

the config therein giving this:

`localhost:~/snap> Magick++-config --cxxflags --libs
-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -fopenmp -MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
-L/usr/local/lib -lMagick++-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI`

and the code runs well enough:

`localhost:~/snap> setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib`
`localhost:~/snap> testIM`
`Here I didit!`

but NOT in the debugger!

`localhost:~/snap> gdb testIM`

`GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.1) 8.1.0.20180409-git`

`...omitted blurb.....`

`Reading symbols from testIM...done.`

`(gdb) run`

`Starting program: /home/acal/snap/testIM`

`/home/acal/snap/testIM: error while loading shared libraries: libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Inferior 1 (process 3847) exited with code 0177]`

`(gdb)`

But the file IS there, and it should be readable:

`-rw-r--r--  1 root root   9406966 2019-10-09 14:39 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.a`

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      1419 2019-10-09 14:39 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.la`

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3979344 2019-10-09 14:47 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so`

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3979344 2019-10-09 14:45 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.4`

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   3979344 2019-10-09 14:39 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.4.0.0`

(2 of the 3 files of equal size were links to the 3rd, I copied the whole file over to see if that was the matter, but no.) Also:

Do you have any idea what the matter could be? The machine is Xubuntu 18.04.

`localhost:~/snap> ldd testIM | grep Magick`

`libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.so.4 (0x00007f0d0a144000)`

`libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.6 (0x00007f0d09697000)`

`libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.6 (0x00007f0d0900c000)`

Thank you for any hint, either to the solution or to further debugging.

Comment: It's great that you managed to solve your own problem! You're encouraged to post your own answer here (but if I remember correctly you'll have to wait a few hours because this is a new account), for the benefit of other people who'll have the same problem.

Comment: However, note that I can't reproduce this. With gdb 7.11.1 on Ubuntu 16.04, if I run `/usr/bin/env` inside gdb, I see the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that was set in the shell that I started gdb from. If I run `set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo` I see `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=foo` in the output. Also modifying shell startup files would not change anything since gdb runs the program directly, it doesn't run a shell. You must have made a mistake in your analysis.

Comment: @gilles, the OP analysis seems right, see the warning at the end of https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html (I think the reason gdb uses the shell to launch the debugged program is for argument processing).

Comment: @AProgrammer Huh, thanks, I didn't know that. So troppapolvere's problem is probably a shell startup file that erases `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.